# .htaccess RewriteRule apache: how to rewrite based on URL parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs with lots of parameters, here is an example that looks like this:

`http://www.mysite.com/profile?reset=1&force=1&gid=9&custom_18=BS+Forestry%2C+University+of+Kentucky`

I would like to do a RewriteRule that redirects any request containing the string:

`&custom`

To a static HTML page such as:

http://www.mysite.com/foo.html

Can someone tell me if/how this is possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should re-think your parameter scheme altogether, if you want decent page rank from search engines.

Comment: awesome idea, but it's not my software so i can't.  i just need to do a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (^|&)custom(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/foo.html [R]
```

Comment: The `(^|&)` and `(&|$)` parts are to allow for cases like `?custom` and `&gid=1&custom`--- while not matching `?**customfield**=irrelevant`

Comment: gracias
you are a kind person

Comment: QUESTION: this doesn't appear to work.  I copied your info verbatim, changing only my domain.  Nothing changed.  I put the code near the top of the .htaccess file above all other ReWriteRules??

Comment: Add the `L` modifier, so the end looks like this: [R,L]. That'll fix the problem. (The L modifier will tell Apache to ignore the rules that you have below.)